# How to save an open .pdf file in Adobe Acrobat 10 with VBA

Tags: vb.net, pdf, save, acrobat, detect

I am writing an application in Microsoft Visual Studio which will open a pdf file from a database.  Acrobat 10 is installed on the host machine.

I want to:

1. Detect that the .pdf file has been opened
2. Save the .pdf file to a given directory once it has been opened

I could always use the mouse pointer to navigate to "file", "save as" and save the file, however I want this to work on multiple machines with varying screen sizes.

I hope there is a way with the supporting libraries that this can be done, thank you!

Comment: Why not save the file directly from the database to the directory?  Should be no need to open it in Acrobat.  BTW your question is tagged as "VBA", which is not the same language as VB.NET

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for pointing out my error in the tag, I will fix that promptly.

I would simply save it from the database, however I am interacting with an old system that needs automation.  When using the system, you click on the screen (after completing some previous steps entering a document number, etc) and a pdf open in Acrobat.  In order to access the pdf later, I need to save it.  

I do not have direct access to the database where the file is pulled, as it is a govenment database that I cannot access unless it is through my work computer.